# Making the background-colour fade out in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a 16x16 grid in which the grid background appears green when you hover your mouse over it, and then the green fades out after awhile.

For now, I just removed the html class `hover` after 2 seconds by using `setTimeout`, but I can't seem to figure out how to make the grid background fade out instead of disappearing instantly. Can anyone give me some tips on how to do a **fading-out** effect for the grid background?

```js
//16x16 = 257
for (let i = 1; i != 257; i++) {
  const div = document.createElement("div")
  div.textContent = i;
  div.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
    div.classList.add("hover")
    setTimeout(() => {
      div.classList.remove("hover")
    }, 2000)
  })
  document.querySelector(".gridContainer").append(div);
}
```

```css
.gridContainer {
  background-color: rgb(234, 241, 241);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gridContainer>div {
  height: 25px;
  flex: 0 1 5.8%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}

.hover {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  transition: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridContainer"> </div>
```

Comment: @epascarello do you mean changing ```.hover``` to ```:hover```?

Comment: as @epascarello pointed out, you can do it with css only. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)

Comment: Yes and add the transition to the `.gridContainer>div`. You can also add transition-delay to give it a pause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply your CSS transition on the element without the hover class. You can then override it for hover. It's a bit backward from what a person might intuit.

Note that I've moved the hover removal to a mouseout function. That seems more appropriate here.

```js
//16x16 = 257
for (let i = 1; i != 257; i++) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.textContent = i;

  div.addEventListener("mouseover", e => {
    div.classList.add("hover")
  });

  div.addEventListener('mouseout', e => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      div.classList.remove("hover")
    }, 2000)
  });

  document.querySelector(".gridContainer").append(div);
}
```

```css
.gridContainer {
  background-color: rgb(234, 241, 241);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gridContainer>div {
  height: 25px;
  flex: 0 1 5.8%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 2s; /* mouseout transition */
}

.gridContainer>div.hover {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  transition: all 0.3s; /* mouseover transition */
}
```

```html
<div class="gridContainer"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `transition-duration: 100ms;` to the element you want to let fade out. This makes anything that changes the visual state or position to a "smooth" animation

Comment: thank you for your answer, I tried it but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Using `:hover` you can do it in CSS. You can add a pause with `transition-delay`

```js
//16x16 = 257
for (let i = 1; i != 257; i++) {
  const div = document.createElement("div")
  div.textContent = i;
  document.querySelector(".gridContainer").append(div);
}
```

```css
.gridContainer {
  background-color: rgb(234, 241, 241);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gridContainer > div {
  height: 25px;
  flex: 0 1 5.8%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
  transition-delay: 500ms;
  transition: 1s;
}

.gridContainer > div:hover {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  transition: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridContainer"> </div>
```

Comment: The delay doesn't seem to be working properly (and it should be 2s).